# dynamics crm 2011 move javascripts to real files and not inside the crm

Tags: javascript, version-control, resources, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to move all the js code from the CRM UI to my own .js files so I can handle the code inside my source control.

I thought about hooking the entry point and instead of writing the js code, just to reference to my external file (containing the code).

Can you recommend what is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tool:

[CRM 2011 Web Resource Linker/Publisher](http://webresourcelinker.codeplex.com/)

it's a Visual Studio 2012 add-in to manage CRM 2011 Web Resources including JavaScript files.

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand, can I manage the sources on my visual studio solution, and publish it to the CRM its self?

Comment: Yes, you can have your Visual Studio solution (with source control as TFS) and publish the JavaScript resources directly from VS to CRM

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using TFS, or don't want to use Visual Studio to manage all of your javascript files, the [javascript web resource manager](https://jswebresourcemanager.codeplex.com/) is a good tool as well.  It is now only being developed within the confines of the [XRMToolBox](https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/), another excellent tool.